# ElasticSearch Completion Suggestion's indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to understand the indexing process for Completion Suggestion. Referencing the ElasticSearch docs [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing), I was wondering if the **suggestions** couldn't be made against properties of documents already in the index as oppose to create a separate property that would house all the possible terms for auto completion? Meaning for each time I need to index a document..I would make 2 calls..one to index the entire doc and another call to PUT (append) new terms from the newly indexed doc to my suggestion property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to make 2 call. you can index doc and suggestion property in single call

Example Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "completion"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "album" : {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example Doc/Index:

```
PUT /music
{
  "title": "jazz",
  "album": "Wonder Fortune",
  "suggest" : {
    "input": [ "Wonder", "World", "Fortune"],
    "weight" : 37
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Samiul. My last question is, when I index a document do I need to tokenize the *input* for indexing? Example..if I want to autocomplete the term `Jack and Jill went up the hill`...how would I tokenize this for indexing?  **inputs: ["Jack and JIll", "Jack went up the hill" , "Jill went up the hill"]**, I'm not sure if tokenizing the words can be done in code or is there a way somehow in having ElasticSearch tokenize these words for indexing?

Comment: No, you don't need analyzer for suggestion terms. Here is why: (from Elasticsearch documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

`The index analyzer to use, defaults to simple. In case you are wondering why we did not opt for the standard analyzer: We try to have easy to understand behaviour here, and if you index the field content At the Drive-in, you will not get any suggestions for a, nor for d (the first non stopword).`

Comment: OK so if I understood correctly, when I index the document ..I should just have **"suggest" : {"input" : ["Jack and Jill went up the hill"]}** and then ES will then tokenizer the sentence automatically. So if I search for the term *Jill*..it would return the suggestion? 

Reason why I ask is because, ES tokenize suggestions into FST Graph...which searches happens from the left most word..in this case **Jack**...so if I search for a word in the middle of the sentence, say **Jill**, according to ES docs [see here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me), I wouldn't get any suggestions

Comment: @Dean Completion Suggester is prefix so if you type `Jill`, you won't get the suggestion, not with the default simple analyzer. You can define a different analyzer to use, or provide multiple inputs, but bear in mind that completion suggester is designed for fast "search as you type", as opposed to a flexible approach for complex search requirements